# SQL not a group expression. find instructors who teach every course in his/her department

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
select instructor.name, instructor.id
from instructor,teaches,course
where instructor.id = teaches.ID and course.course_id = teaches.course_id
and instructor.dept_name = course.Dept_name
group by instructor.name
```

I am new to sql and nested queries. I am trying to find the instructor name and id, who teaches every course in his or her department.

This is what I have so far. I want to use group by to count the courses they teach and compare to all the courses under that department. but I stuck here, it says SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I don't know how to proceed with this.

```
teaches(ID, course id, sec id, semester, year)
course(course id, title, dept name, credits)
instructor(ID, name, dept name, salary)
```

I am so confused about aggregate functions, and how is a valid group by expression. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The query looks syntactically correct, although the logic may be off.  Are you sure the query you posted is really what is generating this error?

Comment: Take it in small steps.  How do you know which department a teacher is in?  How do you know how many courses a department runs?  How do you know how many courses a teacher teaches?  Have you accounted for teachers in Dept-A who teach a course for Dept-B?  How do you ensure that the teacher is teaching all courses for the department they're in?

Comment: The error is because all the non-aggregate expressions mentioned in the select-list must also be listed in the GROUP BY clause.  You've not listed `instructor.id` in the GROUP BY clause, but it isn't an aggregate expression either.  If you learned MySQL previously, this is some unlearning you've got to do — MySQL allows you to be sloppy but standard SQL does not.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *every*, I presume you mean *all* the courses in a department. Try this:

```
SELECT instructor.name, instructor.id
  FROM instructor
 WHERE 0 = (CASE WHEN 
               ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT teaches.course_id)
                  FROM teaches
                 WHERE teaches.ID = instructor.id) = 
               (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT course.course_id) 
                  FROM course 
                 WHERE course.Dept_name = instructor.dept_name)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
```

Comment: @sgeddes method is more straight forward and conventional.

Comment: Thanks! But there is an error says it's not a group by expression. May I ask what is a valid GROUP BY expression? I seem to have a lot problem when using group by.

Comment: Edited the answer. We wouldn't need `GROUP BY` clause here at all since we are selecting entries from `instructor` table only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your database correctly, here's another approach:

```
select i.id, i.deptname
from instructor i
  join teaches t on i.id = t.id
group by i.id, i.deptname
having count(*) = (
  select count(*)
  from course c 
  where c.deptname = i.deptname)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c339d/1)

This uses a more standard `join` syntax, along with `aggregation` to check the `count` of courses a teacher teaches compared to the overall `count` for that particular department.

Btw, you may need to use `count(distinct courseid)` -- depends on your data and if you may have duplicates.

Comment: when I change the SELECT to select i.name, i.id, it says it's not a group by expression. I am confused about what is a valid group by expression.

Comment: I think the problem is it counts all the course he is teaching, not only from his own department.. not sure how to fix that

Comment: never mind, I made it work finally. Thanks for the help!